# How to set Custom Variable tag in Google Analytics w/ iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I am trying to add a custom variable to Google Analytics using the iOS Swift library:

```
let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker

tracker.set("custom_field" value: "my_value")
```

Here's what I'm trying to create a filter on:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WbOtcwgQqE

How do I properly make that a custom variable so I can add a filter in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're no longer called custom variables, but custom dimensions (CD).

To configure the CD you've specified in the video:

Go to your GA account, go into Admin, under the property that you'd like to create this CD, click on "Custom Definitions" and click on "Custom Dimensions" Like[image]

When you're in, click on "NEW CUSTOM DIMENSION" in red. Name it whatever you want, in this case "userRoles", you can name it "User Roles" as well. Make sure for "Scope" select "User" to learn more about scope: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en&ref_topic=2709827#scope

Save and note the "Index" number for the newly created CD. This is how you reference it in your code, not by "userRole" or "User Role" most likely it will be something like "1" or "customDimension1", for the value you'd just set it to be whatever you want to use to identify the different user roles.

Comment: When I'm creating a segment, would I then filter on "Custom Variable (Value 01)" ?

Comment: You would filter on whatever dimension you named it as in GA. In this case "User Role"